# Swift 4: TimeInterval set to random number each time

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm trying to replicate the default Clock app found on the iPhone in order to learn swift better and get used to different parts of iOS Development.

I'm currently working on the timer section of the app.
I have a DatePicker to get the date and I'm assigning the countdownDuration property to a TimeInterval when the timer starts.
This is giving me a random value each time however (always seems to be around 80.0-120.0)

I fully understand I might have the concept of TimeIntervals wrong but from what I've read online and in the Developer Documentation, I have the concept right?

Here is the code I'm using to run the timer:

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker:UIDatePicker!

var IsTimerRunning:Bool = false;
var TimerDuration:TimeInterval = 0;

var timer:Timer?;

//Called every second when timer is running
@objc func onTimerFires() {
    TimerDuration = TimerDuration - 1.0;
    print (TimerDuration);
    if (TimerDuration <= 0.0) {
        EndTimer();
    }
}

func EndTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate();
    IsTimerRunning = false;
}

//Start button pressed
@IBAction func StartButtonPressed() {
    if (IsTimerRunning == false) {
        TimerDuration = datePicker.countDownDuration;

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(onTimerFires), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        IsTimerRunning = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Timers do not work for things like this, right? soon as the app is pushed into the background or terminated your timer is gone. You need something more robust.

Comment: or you can try to put timer on main thread `DispatchQueue.main.async { Timer.scheduledTimer(...` (not a solution to use in real app, just as an exercise)

Comment: Did you configure your date picker as a countdown picker (mode = .countDownTimer)?

Comment: Check if this solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384427/strange-date-picker-behaviour-xcode-swift-3?rq=1

Comment: By the way, the use of all of those semicolons, the parentheses around `if` test, etc., is distinctly unswifty. Also, as a matter of convention, we always start property and method names with lowercase letters, e.g. `timerDuration` instead of `TimerDuration`, etc.

Comment: You should never count on a timer to keep track of elapsed time. Use a date to store the start time (or the end time in the future) and display the time interval since now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of considerations:

1. Make sure your date picker has a Mode of countDownTimer. As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/1615986-countdownduration) says:

   > If the mode of the date picker is not `UIDatePicker.Mode.countDownTimer`, this value [`countDownDuration`] is undefined...
2. If you added this on IB, you may want to set "date" property to "Custom". As the documentation warns us:

   > **Note**
   >
   > When you use Interface Builder to set the Mode attribute to *Count Down Timer* and specify a value for the timer attribute, your date picker may not respect the Timer attribute value when you build and run your project. If this happens, return to the Attributes inspector for the date picker, select Custom in the Date pop-up menu (you can ignore the associated value), and rebuild your project.

   I notice very strange `countDownDuration` values until I selected "custom" for the "Date" pop-up menu in IB.

Comment: I had selected countDownTimer as the mode for date picker, but not Custom date. After I did this, the timer works flawlessly (very strange).. Thanks!